# Will postgres performance be affected if ksuids are prefixed?

Tags: database, postgresql, indexing

I am planning to use [ksuids](https://github.com/segmentio/ksuid) (random ordered values loosely based on time) prefixed with resource types for eg `order_0ujsswThIGTUYm2K8FjOOfXtY1K` as the primary key for a table(s). The access patterns are mostly exact matches and indexes are btrees. There are few SO questions wrt  prefixes with like queries but not exact matches.

Engine: Postgres 11

1. Am I negating some of the benefits offered by ksuids in this case? (better cache locality and faster inserts)
2. Am I better off storing just the ksuid part without prefix
   `0ujsswThIGTUYm2K8FjOOfXtY1K`?
3. How is btree generally affected with prefixes?

Comment: Please explain what segmention_ksuids is instead of adding a link to it. Prefixes on column names won't affect query performance at all. Prefixes on table values may have a marginal effect on indexes under specific conditions.

Comment: Corrected the part on segmentio ksuid. I am looking at prefixes for table values. Is there some resource I can refer to for these marginal effects / specific conditions?

Meanwhile I am benchmarking using pgbench but any pointers in general are helpful